# C# call server service from wcf web service

Tags: wcf

I have developed a WCF Web Service using C# that works and serves up the data I need to my mobile client using a COBOL VM that talks to my backend data.  It works, but it is very unreliable.  I think it has to do with the lifecycle of the web service and I just don't understand how it is breaking down.  I believe the problem is the COOBL VM, which is a singleton, and the process of shutting it down each time.  I've already tried

```
lock(myobject)
{
... run my code here
}
```

I want to move the COBOL VM to a server service where I can persist my COBOL VM and just make calls to it.  I don't know how to persist the COBOL VM across all WCF Web Service calls.  I'm looking for examples the show a wcf web service communicating with a server service so I can move my business layer code out of the service and just have it make calls to the server service for the data it needs.  This way I can keep the COBOL VM running all the time rather than going through a load-up, execute, and then shutdown process as I'm doing in the Web Service.

Does anyone have any GOOD examples of a WCF Web Service communicating with a WCF Server Service?

Comment: What do you mean by "Server Service"? A WCF web service already is on a server. It's not very clear what architecture you're trying to set up. Also, what exactly is the COBOL VM? Is it a VM in the sense of a language interpreter, like the JVM? Or a virtualised computer, like VMWare?

Comment: The VM is an execution environment that is instantiated though an object.  It would probably be similar to the Java VM, though I haven't looked at Java's execution architecture.  I'm trying to setup an architecture allows me to execute a COBOL program against a VM that can only be instantiated once (Singleton).  I want to prevent more than one request to the VM object, because it doesn't appear to be thread safe (thus the attempt with lock) and requests are stepping on each other.  My idea is to to a server service so the VM can stay running.  Hoping for examples of web srv to srv service.

Answer (score 1):

> keep the COBOL VM running all the time rather than going through a load-up, execute, and then shutdown process as I'm doing in the Web Service.

Then create a Windows service that hosts this VM client, so you only have to connect once and can keep it running. Then you can let that service also host a WCF service, which then queries the VM client.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing in your answer.  My original question already detailed that this was the direction I was thinking of going, but that I couldn't figure out how to get the web service to communicate with the server service.  That part might have been poorly explained by me.  Either way, it doesn't answer the question at the end: Does anyone have any GOOD examples of a WCF Web Service communicating with a WCF Server Service?

Comment: @Martin [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.100).aspx). Then let the WCF ServiceHost object communicate with the code for the Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off looking into a CORBA solution - CORBA is the only remoting technology that can give you access into an already running process.